# GParted FAT32 RAID10 resize running for 18+ hours

Tags: partitioning, gparted, raid

I am trying to resize a FAT32 partition on a software RAID 10 from 1.7 TiB to 700 GiB.

- I am not moving the beginning of the partition, only the end
- iotop shows 90+ percent IO for gpartedbin
- It has been running (and is still running) for over 18 hours now
- The partition contains around 500 GiB of data, so it will be pretty full once the resize is done

Is it safe to assume it is stuck and cancel it?

EDIT a day later: It actually took that long. 38 hours for a partition that was less than two GiB in size...
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlONZ.png)

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui It is not in my oppinion, in the answer it says that it should not take a whole day (which it is taking now).

Comment: RAID 10 is slow in writing, fast in reading.  Ping me if it takes more than 2 days.

Comment: @kaesaecracker true, but remember that the OP in that question have a 500GB disk while yours in much larger

Comment: As long as there was still IO happening on the drive I would leave it alone.

Comment: Less than 48 hours, but still a long time! *Patience is a virtue!*  **;-)**